# interactiveView child of SingleChildScrollView in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

i have an intractiveView as child of SingleChildScrollView
my problem is that at first when i want to scroll interactiveView down it only scrolls singleChildScrollView but if i scroll left or right at first then scroll down and up it it would scroll my interactiveView unlike first attempt.
how can i fix this?

```
InteractiveViewer(
              panEnabled: true,
              minScale: 1.0,
              maxScale: 5.0,
              child: Container(
                image...
               ))
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this?

Comment: @AlexSullivan No And i do not think there is a soloution to this